# Export native class (type) instances over React Native Bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on trying to implement a native iOS SDK for React Native. So far, I've been able to initiate the main module and methods following the documentation, but am having an issue when it comes to class instances.

Here's my scenario. Let's say the `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` takes a callback that will return some state from the SDK. This state is an instance of a class in the SDK, complete with some methods and props. I can easily convert the properties into a `NSDictionary` and serialize that to the app, but I'm not sure how to handle the methods.

I can add them on my main module, but I don't like the pattern of having all the sub class modules exposed on the main one. In addition, since the methods are specific to the instance, I'm not sure how you would specify in the app which instance to call the method on.

My understanding of the Native Modules is that they're more of the singleton pattern than class, so even if I made native modules for each of the SDK class types with their own `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` calls, I can't figure out how to determine which SDK instance to use for the module.

Here is a quick example of the some of the classes I'm trying to convert.

```
Channels
  NSArray<Channel*> *listOfChannels;
  - (void)refresh;

Channel
  NSString *name;
  NSDictionary *attributes;
  NSArray<Message*> *messages;
  - (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;
  - (void)setName:(NSString *)name;
  - (void)postToChannel:(Message *)message;
```

I hope this all makes sense.. any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Yes, I don't love it but basically used singletons as needed and when there were multiple nested classes I kept a Dictionary/Map of the instances and referenced them from the JS client code with sids. I'll post a more coherent answer in a bit.